# C linking error: undefined reference to 'main'

Tags: c, linker

I am attempting to link several C programs together, and I am getting an error in response:

```
$ gcc -o runexp.o scd.o data_proc.o -lm -fopenmp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: * [runexp] Error 1
```

I have exactly one main function and it is in runexp. The form is

```
int main(void) {
    ...; 
    return 0;
}
```

Why might I get this error?

Comment: is this function at global scope?

Comment: your GCC command doesn't include runexp.c, it OUTPUTS to runexp.o - sure you're including the source file with the main method ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should provide output file name after `-o` option. In your case `runexp.o` is treated as output file name, not input object file and thus your `main` function is undefined.

Comment: Or just remove the `-o` option and use the conventional `./a.out`, which is a beautiful name ;)

Answer (score 11):

You're not including the C file that contains `main()` when compiling, so the linker isn't seeing it.

You need to add it:

```
$ gcc -o runexp runexp.c scd.o data_proc.o -lm -fopenmp
```

Answer (score 4):

You are overwriting your object file `runexp.o` by running this command :

```
 gcc -o runexp.o scd.o data_proc.o -lm -fopenmp
```

In fact, the `-o` is for the **output** file.
You need to run :

```
gcc -o runexp.out runexp.o scd.o data_proc.o -lm -fopenmp
```

**runexp.out** will be you binary file.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you compile most .c files in the following way:

gcc foo.c -o foo. It might vary depending on what #includes you used or if you have any external .h files. Generally, when you have a C file, it looks somewhat like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    /* any other includes, prototypes, struct delcarations... */
    int main(){
    */ code */
}
```

When I get an 'undefined reference to main', it usually means that I have a .c file that does not have `int main()` in the file. If you first learned java, this is an understandable manner of confusion since in Java, your code usually looks like the following:

```
//any import statements you have
public class Foo{
    int main(){}
 }
```

I would advise looking to see if you have `int main()` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

### ld linker error: `` undefined reference to `main' `` in C++:

I know this question is about C, but if you stumble here and happen to be compiling in C++ (as was my case), it may be because you have your `main()` function inside of a namespace. Move it *outside* the namespace and it will fix this error!

Ex:

[will_not_run.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/namespace_around_main__undefined_reference_to_main_when_linking.cpp):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// <========== comment out the namespace (this lines plus the opening and 
// closing braces) to make this program link!
namespace my_module
{

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello world!\n\n";

    return 0;
}

} // namespace my_module
```

If you try to build and run with this command:

```bash
time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu++17 will_not_run.cpp \
    -o will_not_run && will_not_run
```

...you'll get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To fix this, simply delete the namespace, or move `main()` outside of it, and it works just fine again!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello world!\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

So, if you need to access your `my_module` namespace inside the `main()` function, simply be explicit, and use it as `my_module::my_func()` or whatever, or call `using namespace my_module;` in whichever scope you'd like to have access to your namespaced content within your `main()` function.